# Normal Distribution $E(X^4)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

So I have the Normal Distribution $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}.$

I know any $E(Z^{\mbox{ (any odd #)}})$ makes you integrate an odd function thus giving an answer of zero (i.e. $E(Z^1)$ and $E(Z^3)$ both $=0$).

And I know computing $E(Z^2)$ shows some links to the Gamma function/distributions and helps the integration and gives the answer of $1.$

However, I'm having difficulty figuring $E(Z^4).$
I know $\displaystyle E(Z^4) = \int \left[z^4 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\right] dz,$
then I do 
$\displaystyle 2 \cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \left[\frac{z^2}{2} e^{-z^2/2}\right] d\left(\frac{z^2}{2}\right).$

This is similar to the Gamma function $\Gamma(\alpha)= \int t^{\alpha-1} e^{-t}.$ 
However, my "$t$" in my problem $[(z^2)/2]$ doesn't have an $(\alpha-1)$, it's just to the first power. Any suggestions of how to manipulate it better to form a better gamma function to solve the problem for $E(X^4)$?

Thanks a lot

Comment: or just use the moment generating function?

Comment: @Slungpue, I agree, however my professor wants us to know how to do it using this method for our test.

Comment: Make the substitution $x^2/2 = y$ to get a Gamma function.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am aware of that substitution and pointed that out in the problem, My problem is I don't know what to make for (alpha-1) within the problem and more speficially what my alpha can be since in the problem, the (z^2 /2) is only raised to the first power

Comment: I can't figure out where exactly your difficulty with Gamma function is arising, but if you don't want to use substitution, use integration by parts: $$\int x^ne^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm dx = -x^{n-1}e^{-x^2/2} + (n-1)\int x^{n-2}e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Why not $\Gamma(2)$? Then $\alpha-1 = 2-1 = 1.$

Comment: `Why not Γ(2)? Then α−1=2−1=1.` Huh?

Comment: $\Gamma(2)$ because OP incorrectly said the exponent is $1$. Actually, the exponent is $3/2$ and you can use $\Gamma(5/2)$ (see answer already posted by Indrajit).

Comment: The problem is a little easier to see when the formulas are formatted in LaTeX. There are two integrals in one paragraph that I think are supposed to be equal but are not equal.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $\frac{z^{2}}{2}=t$, then $zdz=dt$ and $z^{3}=(2t)^{3/2}$.
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}[Z^{4}]&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}z^{4}e^{-z^{2}/2}\;dz\\
&=&\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{4}e^{-z^{2}/2}\;dz\\
&=&\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}(2t)^{3/2}e^{-t}\;dt\\
&=&\frac{2^{5/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{5/2-1}e^{-t}\;dt\\
&=&\frac{2^{5/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Gamma(5/2)\\
&=&\frac{2^{5/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\\
&=&3.
\end{eqnarray}
I am using the facts that $\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$ and $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$.