# If X is a random variable having the standard normal distribution and Y=X^2, are X and Y independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence

When given a random variable X that has standard normal distribution and Y=X^2, how can we determine if X and Y are independent of each other?

I know a way to do it is proving P(X ≤ 1, Y ≤ 1) ≠ P(X ≤ 1) P(Y ≤ 1) but I am unsure how to start the proof.

In addition, how would we find the cov(X, Y). I know independent events have covariance of 0 but if these events are dependent, how would we go about doing this?

Comment: Note that $P(Y > 1 | X > 1) = 1,$ while $P(Y > 1)$ is strictly less than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$cov (X,Y)=EXY-(EX)(EY)=EX^{3}-(EX)(EX)^{2})=0$ since al odd moments of standard normal distribution are $0$ (by symmetry of the density function around $0$).

[$P(X\leq 1, Y\leq 1)=P(X\leq 1, -1\leq X\leq 1)=P(-1\leq X \leq 1)$ and $P(X\leq 1)P( Y\leq 1)=P(X\leq 1)P(-1\leq X\leq 1)\neq P(-1\leq X \leq 1)$].

Intuitively a r.v. $X$ and a function of $X$ are not independent except is some very trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

From $\text{Var}[X] = \text{E}[X^2] - (\text{E}[X])^2$ and parameters of the normal distribution $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ we obtain $\text{E}[X^2] = \sigma^2+\mu^2$

For $\text{cov}[X, X^2] = \text{E}[X^3] - \text{E}[X]\text{E}[X^2]$ we have

$$\text{E}[X^3] = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^3 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\;dx$$

Let $\displaystyle u = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}, du = \frac{dx}{\sigma}, x = u\sigma + \mu$

There are probably better methods, but following [Normal Distribution $E(X^4)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990833/normal-distribution-ex4) and binomial expansion we could at least do

$$\text{E}[X^3] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [u^3\sigma^3 + 3u^2\sigma^2\mu + 3u\sigma\mu^2 + \mu^3]\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right)du$$

The odd terms of $u$ yield zero for the integral by symmetry of odd functions, so we are left with

$$\text{E}[X^3] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [3u^2\sigma^2\mu + \mu^3]\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right)du$$

The $\mu^3$ term is easiest, this is just standardized normal distribution so that term (distributing $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$) goes to $1 \times \mu^3$. Some clean-up and following instructions as above post we obtain

$$\text{E}[X^3] = \mu^3 + \frac{12\sigma^2\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^2}{2} \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right)du$$

Let $t = \frac{u^2}{2}, u = \sqrt{2t}, du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}dt$

$$\text{E}[X^3] = \mu^3 + \frac{6\sigma^2\mu}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}t^{1.5 - 1} \exp(-t)dt = \mu^3 + \frac{6\sigma^2\mu}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(1.5) = \mu^3 + 3\sigma^2\mu$$

As $\Gamma(1.5) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. $\text{cov}[X, X^2] = \mu^3 + 3\sigma^2\mu - \mu(\sigma^2+\mu^2) = \boxed{2\sigma^2\mu}$.

For the standard normal distribution the covariance is 0, yet $X$ and $Y$ remain dependent. There are many ways to show the dependence. A simple contradiction would suffice.

Also see [Show that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, but nevertheless Cov$[X,Y] = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754649/show-that-random-variables-x-and-y-are-not-independent-but-nevertheless-cov?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}\ P(Y=x^2|X=x)=1$$ this should be enough to state that $Y$ is dependent on $X$